# Choosing suitable simulator for a swarm of AUVs

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, simulator, webots, auv

Which of the following simulators is the best choice for simulating a swarm of AUVs working together to perform a mission? Please clarify your reason and if you know any better choice, I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly help me. Please consider the need for doing Hardware-In-The-Loop(HIL) simulation.

1. Webots
2. V-REP
3. [AUV Workbench](https://savage.nps.edu/AuvWorkbench/)
4. Gazebo
5. UWSim
6. [SwarmSimX](http://homepages.laas.fr/afranchi/robotics/?q=node/120)

In addition, notice that capability to connect to the middle-wares like ROS is really important.

The other option is using a game engine like Blender but I think it needs a lot of developing effort and is time-consuming! Would you recommend this approach be used? If not, why not? And what would you recommend instead?

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Hossein, but I'm afraid that this kind of question isn't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. If you explain what problem you are trying to solve, what you have tried and what problems you had, we might be better able to help.

Answer (score 1):

We are using for the AUV-Avalon a simulation called Mars

http://rock-robotics.org/master/documentation/simulation/index.html

Unfortunately there is no ROS integration, but a Rock integration.
Rock supports HIL in general.

For AUVs there are multiple integrations available which are collected in the mars-core package https://github.com/rock-simulation/orogen-mars_core

Mars does not provide hydrodynamic calculation, but the mars-core package provide a fossen-based model for auv motion-simulation.

The documentation therefore is (unfortunately) not finished yet but you can take a look to: https://gitorious.org/rock-tutorials/orogen-auv_simulation

The main advantage is the same interface for simulated and real systems. Rock also provides a lot of (auv) tooling.

But in the end the question is what exactly do you want to simulation, mission-planning, sensors, motion estimation. I think you have to specify this to find a good answer.